# Bean Validation Collection of String not Blank

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a collection of strings, now I want to make sure that not only the collection is not empty but also each string in that collection does not contain a blank input.

```
 @NotEmpty
 public List<String> getDescriptions() // not empty collection


 @NotEmpty @NotBlank
 public List<String> getDescriptions() // NotBlank isn't applicable on collections
```

Is there a way other then to wrap the string into a class or create a custom @NotBlankCollectionEntries?

Comment: it is not a duplicate! IMO, The question assumes the object in the collection is not an primitive and thus can hold constraints. I can't add a valid constraint in string without wrapping it.

Answer (score 9):

```
@NotEmpty
public List<@NotBlank String> getDescriptions();
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use something like this:

````
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
public List<@NotBlank @Size(max = 123) String> getDescriptions() // not empty collection


@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
public List<@NotBlank @Size(max = 123)> getDescriptions()```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the hibernate constraint `@NotBlank` with a further implementation of `ConstraintValidator<NotBlank, List<String>>`. This is described in [**8.1.2. Overriding constraint definitions in XML**](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml-mapping-constraintdefinition). This new validator can be concatenated to the existing built-in validators with the XML element `<constraint-definition>` in your [**META-INF/validation.xml**](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml-config) file:

```
<constraint-definition annotation="org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank">
    <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
        <value>com.acme.app.constraint.NotBlankValidatorForStringList</value>
    </validated-by>
</constraint-definition>
```

Answer (score -1):

Annotate the field with @Valid annotation to validate the elements inside the collection.

```
 @NotEmpty 
 @NotBlank
 @Valid
 public List<String> getDescriptions()
```